# In Schwartz space, do we have that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^\alpha f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty $ or $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|(1+|x|^\alpha) f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

In Schwartz space, it's function $\mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)$ such that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^\alpha f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty $$ or such that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|(1+|x|^\alpha) f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty,$$
for all $\alpha \in N$ and all $n\in\mathbb N$ ? Because sometime I see the first one, and sometime the second one... so Why do we have those two way of definition ? And what is the best one and why ?

Answer (score 2):

Both are equivalent ! If $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^\alpha f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty $ for all $\alpha $, then $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|(1+|x|^\alpha )f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty.$$

Conversely, if $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|(1+|x|^\alpha )f^{(n)}(x)|<\infty $, since 
$$|x^\alpha f^{(n)}(x) |\leq |(1+|x|^\alpha)f^{(n)}(x)|,$$
the claim follow. There is not a better definition. The first one is more visual, the second one is better for integrability problems.